# Word for a character's history after the end of the movie

Tags: word-request

Often in the movies based on real life incidents, the ending credits say what happened to character after the point where the movie ended. For example

> X is now the manger of a football team.
>
> Y is now living with A in Z country.
>
> R was arrested for possession of drug in 1997 and is in jail.

So I want to describe it like this

> The movie ends with ending credits revealing the **development/progress** with the character featured in the movie.

Both **development/progress** here are positive words meaning something good happening the characters, However it does not necessarily have to be positive as shown in the example with R.

Can anyone suggest me the appropriate word for **development/progress** in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common word for this is ***epilogue*** (also spelled *epilog*). According to NOAD:

> **epilogue** (also *epilog*)
>   (*n*.) a section or speech at the end of a book or play that serves as a comment on or a conclusion to what has happened.

The word might be used in a context like this (near the end of a movie):

> This is a great movie; I hope they give an epilogue.
>   Yes, I agree. If they don't, the first thing I'm doing when we get home is check Wikipedia.

Interestingly enough, you'll sometimes see such epilogues in fictional works, too. A famous example is the end of the movie *Animal House*.

Answer (score 1):

There is the common phrase **Where are they now?**
Also there used to be an American TV program with the same name. It featured well known people from the past, and told about there lives since that time. In many cases this was child actors who had since grown up.